# .htaccess - Redirect www and non www of my domain to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a domain name www.example.com. Also I've a blog installed in this domain under the directory blog. www.example.com/blog is the blog URL of my site.

I need to redirect www.example.com and example.com to www.example.com/blog through htacess file. Currently my htaccess does redirect www.example.com to www.example.com/blog. But it redirects non-www URL example.com to www.example.com/blog

I'm not sure how to solve this issue. This is my htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/blog/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ blog [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /blog/
```